# Slick 3.2: Unable to perform upsert operation using mysql

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, slick

I am using slick 3.2 for creating simple CRUD application, but while performing `upsert` operations, the record is not updated. But in logs, it seems like, the record is updated. Following is my code:

```
private val product = TableQuery[Products]
override def updateProduct(id: Int, row: ProductsRow): Future[Int] = db.run {
    product.insertOrUpdate(row)
  }

ProductsRow(3,'PULLY','DDD',new TimeStamp(new Data().getTime), 4, 202, -1)
```

My Logs are:

```
[debug] s.j.J.statement - Preparing statement: insert into `mae_app`.`products` (`id`,`name`,`code`,`date`,`quantity`,`price`,`company_id`)  values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) on duplicate key update `name`=VALUES(`name`), `code`=VALUES(`code`), `date`=VALUES(`date`), `quantity`=VALUES(`quantity`), `price`=VALUES(`price`), `company_id`=VALUES(`company_id`)
[debug] s.j.J.parameter - /-----+--------+--------+-------------------------+-----+------------+-----\
[debug] s.j.J.parameter - | 1   | 2      | 3      | 4                       | 5   | 6          | 7   |
[debug] s.j.J.parameter - | Int | String | String | Timestamp               | Int | BigDecimal | Int |
[debug] s.j.J.parameter - |-----+--------+--------+-------------------------+-----+------------+-----|
[debug] s.j.J.parameter - | 3   | PULLY  | DDD    | 2017-08-03 10:17:47.144 | 4   | 205.0      | -1  |
[debug] s.j.J.parameter - \-----+--------+--------+-------------------------+-----+------------+-----/
```

The logs seems like, record is updated with new values, but while we are check into database, db still have old record values.

It seems like, generated sql query is not correct like `on duplicate key update`name`=VALUES(`name`)`  statement contains `name` filed, rather then name field value. I am not able to figure out, what exact problem is? So, how to resolve the problem?

Comment: I can't see where you invoke the `updateProduct` method. Only declaration of this method is in you code snippet.

Comment: @AlexanderArendar I am not post my whole code here, just assume like, this method will invoke. and I am using mysql for database.

Comment: Probably the whole code is not needed for people who can help you. But still I think to see the `Products` declaration (because there you define primary key, etc.) and how exactly you invoke the `updateProduct` method is necessary.

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara Can you post the slick mapping of the Products table?
and why do you need `id` in `updateProduct` function?